# How to distinguish two entities that can play the same role at a given moment

Tags: mysql, sql

I am modeling data from a system.

I have a PATIENT entity. This entity can connect to the site to retrieve his medical data.

Also I want to create a USER entity for those have permission to act on the site (admin, supervisor and input operators).

Since the patient can connect to the site and retrieve information about him, and that members of the service can do the same thing,
is the Patient entity not confused in this case with the User entities?

Or should we distinguish the two entites?

Thank you.

I have created entity PATIENT, but i am in doubt.

Comment: It's up to you. As I see it, there are two distinct entities: patients and users. Anyone whose medical data is stored on the system is a patient. Anyone who accesses the system to look at patient data is a user; it so happens that there will be some users who only have access to one patient's medical data (i.e. their own)

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of defining the data model, you seem to have a situation where patients are users.

This simply suggests having two separate entities, with the user id being a property of the patient.  So:

```
create table users (
    user_id int auto_increment primary key,
    -- information about users
    . . .
);

create table patients (
    patient_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int,
    -- information about patients
    . . .
    constraint fk_patients_user_id foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
);
```

Then you can start defining roles, such as "viewer", "editor", "maintainer" and provide a table that assigns roles to users -- and only to users.  For patients, the default role would be "view only my own records".  Others might have broader roles.